# Action Button Not Appearing in Notification iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, unusernotificationcenter

I am using local push notifications in my app. when added action button for the notification in iOS 10, it doesn't appear below the notification. the notification is appearing, but the action button is missing at the bottom of the notification. The appdelegate code is given below.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {(accepted, error) in
      if !accepted {
        print("Notification access denied.")
      }
    }
    let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "markCompleted", title: "Mark as Completed", options: [])
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "todoList", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    return true
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
  }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
  }


  // MARK: - user defined functions

  func notifyWithinApp(_ message: String) {
    Utils.sharedInstance.notifyLocally(message)
  }

  func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, body: String) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Dont Forget"
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }


  // MARK: - Core Data stack

  lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
      /*
       The persistent container for the application. This implementation
       creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
       application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
       error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
      */
      let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ListTodo")
      container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
          if let error = error as NSError? {
              // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
              // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

              /*
               Typical reasons for an error here include:
               * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
               * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
               * The device is out of space.
               * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
               Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
               */
              fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
          }
      })
      return container
  }()

  // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

  func saveContext () {
      let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
      if context.hasChanges {
          do {
              try context.save()
          } catch {
              // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
              // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
              let nserror = error as NSError
              fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
          }
      }
  }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    // Print message ID.
    // Print full message.
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if response.actionIdentifier == "markCompleted" {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @ZuzanaPaulis yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually i didnt swipe the notification. then i found that the button appears only when you swipe the notification. Terrible UI/UX design by Apple.

Comment: I too faced the same problem but after swiping down the attachment and action buttons show up . Phew !! Thanks Ganesh.

Answer (score 13):

The buttons do not appear on their own. On supported devices you have to 3D touch the notifications to show the content or buttons. On non-supported devices you can try swiping down or left/right for the buttons to show.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Dude, thank you so much, saved me literally hours of BS. Wow, I don't know if this is a PEBKAC issue, or just really unintuitive UX.

Comment: Nice article showing the differences between iOS9/10 and between older / 3D touch devices. https://news.dueapp.com/ios-10-notifications-one-step-forward-one-step-back-fe712469184e

Comment: What NYC Tech Engineer said.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem. 3D touch function availability is vital for displaying buttons. Run your app in iPhone 5s simulator - buttons will appear after you'll swipe notification to the left.